# CSS ~ selector vs + selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[According to W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

> - `div + p {}` selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements
> - `p ~ div` selects every `<div>` element that is preceded by a `<p>` element

So what's the difference?

I am trying to make a `<div id="bar">` appear when `<div id="foo">` is on hover, and in my CSS both `#foo:hover ~ #bar` and `#foo:hover + #bar` seem to do the exact same thing.

[Fiddle with `~` selector](https://jsfiddle.net/wcx9z75r/)

[Fiddle with `+` selector](https://jsfiddle.net/nLkp1h4b/)

```css
#foo,
#bar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#foo {
  background-color: indianred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#bar {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

/* Example 1 */
#foo:hover ~ #bar {
  visibility: visible;
}
/* Example 2 */
#foo:hover + #bar {
  visibility: visible;
}
/* Both example 1 & 2 do the same thing */
```

```html
<div id="foo">

</div>

<div id="bar">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple demonstration of the difference

First `+`

Selects **only** the `p` **immediately** following the `div`

```css
div+p {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  SOME DIV
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore unde ipsam iusto veniam, neque natus perferendis pariatur, ipsa doloremque odit atque sunt vitae. Tempore iste nesciunt sint assumenda accusamus dolorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae sint, ullam reiciendis officia placeat tenetur enim harum eos adipisci natus quis totam corrupti nostrum at sunt ipsam labore dolor voluptate.</p>
```

and `~` selects **all** `p` following the `div`.

```css
div~p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  SOME DIV
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore unde ipsam iusto veniam, neque natus perferendis pariatur, ipsa doloremque odit atque sunt vitae. Tempore iste nesciunt sint assumenda accusamus dolorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae sint, ullam reiciendis officia placeat tenetur enim harum eos adipisci natus quis totam corrupti nostrum at sunt ipsam labore dolor voluptate.</p>
```

Comment: I don't understand ... there is no explanation of the CSS selectors and how they work. 

Comment: @TheStackOverflowCommunity the demo is self-explanatory, simply run it and you will understand. Sometimes words aren't needed to explain things.